# Unable to access xampp files because of user permissions problem

Tags: permission, apache

I've installed [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) on my MacBook with macOS 10.12, Sierra. Everything works fine, but I created php app with slim framework witch creates cache files.

The problem is that I have no permissions to these files, I can not delete them because this files belongs to user daemon.

I've tried to change user in xampp `https.conf` but when I change user to my username apache will not start:

```
ERROR: Failed to restart "apache": cannot stop service: AH00543: httpd: bad user name
```

Anybody know how to deal with this problem?

**UPDATE:**

folder path is nfs://192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/htdocs/2017/cache

I try this command when I am in 2017 folder:

**sudo chmod -R +a "staff allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" cache**

And i get

chmod: Failed to set ACL on file 'cache': Operation not supported

chmod: Failed to set ACL on file '5d': Operation not supported

chmod: Failed to set ACL on file 'dc': Operation not supported

chmod: Failed to set ACL on file '5ddcda0f8a5b896924f37eaa7d4701bffab1d462': Operation not supported

**sudo chmod -R 777 cache**

chmod: Unable to change file mode on cache/5d: Operation not permitted

chmod: Unable to change file mode on cache/5d/dc: Operation not permitted

chmod: Unable to change file mode on cache/5d/dc/5ddcda0f8a5b896924f37eaa7d4701bffab1d462: Operation not permitted

**UPDATE**

Problem solved by install older version of xampp witch files are not in network shared folder but in /Applications/Xampp

There is no problem with virtual hosts and folders permissions

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Network Drive Limitation

You likely can not change the permissions of using the network shared drive, `nfs`, path. Instead use the approach below on the Mac involved, using the local paths.

### Changing Permissions

You can grant yourself access to the daemon's files using the Finder's **Get Info** panel.

[image: macOS Get Info]

1. Within the Finder, select the folder you want access to;
2. Select **File (menu) > Get Info**;
3. Within **Sharing & Permissions** click the **+** and add your user account;
4. Within **Sharing & Permissions** click the cog and select **Apply to enclosed items**.

You may need to unlock the permissions settings using the **Lock** on the lower-right of the panel.

### Command line approach

Alternatively, you can use the command line to change permissions, see [Permissions for new files in shared directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5689). The command line approach is more capable and allows `sudo` to ensure you have permissions to make the change.

#### Locked files and `chmod` errors

See [Why does chown report “Operation not permitted” on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/279235)

Comment: Thx, but when i try to do this, I get:

The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission.

Comment: See the updated answer mentioning a `sudo` command line approach; this should ensure you have appropriate permissions – assuming System Integrity Protection (SIP) is not stopping you.

Comment: When i try this command i get:

chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file cache: Operation not supported
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file 5d: Operation not supported
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file dc: Operation not supported
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file 5ddcda0f8a5b896924f37eaa7d4701bffab1d462: Operation not supported

Comment: Please could you edit your question and add the path to the files you want to change and the complete `chmod` command you are seeing errors from.

Comment: ok, question is updated

Comment: To work, I suspect the `chmod` command, or Get Info, needs to be applied to a local folder and not a network shared folder.

Comment: Thx for you answer, I've install older xampp version, there is no problem with virtual host and access to files because xampp files are not in network shared folder